# Keep getting this error: "variable total might not have been initialized"

Tags: java, user-interface, switch-statement

I really don't know what is the problem because total is initialized as the program will always start with case 1 because click initially is equal to 1. Where do I have to initialize it, or what is the problem?

```
enterBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
               {

                switch(click)
                    {

                      case 1:
                          double subtotal = Double.parseDouble(Atext.getText());
                          double total = 0.05*Math.round(1.13*subtotal/0.05);
                          answer.setText("The total will be $" + total + " (tax included). Enter the amount of money the customer gave.");
                          int click = 2;

                      case 2:
                          double money = Double.parseDouble(Atext.getText());
                          click = 3;
                          if (money<total)
                          {
                              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "That is not enough money.");
                              click = 2;
                          }
                    }

               }

        });
```

Comment: Can you state which line gives the error?

Comment: You need to init it either in every `switch` branch where you use it or before `switch`

Comment: Because `click` might not have been initialized. That warning doesn't fake-run your code to see if it's a reasonable value. If it's a class variable it's a little sketchy anyway.

Answer (score 4):

you need put the definition of total outside switch, like this:

```
enterBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
             double total = 0;
            switch(click)
                {

                  case 1:
                      double subtotal = Double.parseDouble(Atext.getText());
                      total = 0.05*Math.round(1.13*subtotal/0.05);
                      answer.setText("The total will be $" + total + " (tax included). Enter the amount of money the customer gave.");
                      int click = 2;

                  case 2:
                      double money = Double.parseDouble(Atext.getText());
                      click = 3;
                      if (money<total)
                      {
                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "That is not enough money.");
                          click = 2;
                      }
                }

           }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize 'total' to 0 before your switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Scope of variable in each `case` is corresponds to whole switch statement

```
switch(key) {
case 0:
    String str="zero";
    break;

case 1:
    str="One";
    break;

}
```

but if you create `case` with braces then you need to declare it either in each `case` or above the `switch` statement

```
switch(key) {
case 0:{
    String str="zero";
    break;
    }
case 1:{
    String str="One";
    break;
}
}
```

OR

```
String str;
switch(key) {
case 0:{
     str="zero";
    break;
}
case 1:{
     str="One";
    break;
}
}
```